# A connection attempt failed error when accessing MongoDB under load test

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We're beginning to leverage MongoDB for search functionality in our application, to improve performance over how we used to do searches with SQL Server. Individual testing works fine, however now we've begun load testing with 40 concurrent "users" executing searches against MongoDB at once. Part way through each load test, many of the calls start erroring:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessage(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.ReceiveMessage(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocol[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.Command[TResult](ICoreSession session, ReadPreference readPreference, DatabaseNamespace databaseNamespace, BsonDocument command, IEnumerable`1 commandPayloads, IElementNameValidator commandValidator, BsonDocument additionalOptions, Action`1 postWriteAction, CommandResponseHandling responseHandling, IBsonSerializer`1 resultSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocol(IChannelHandle channel, ICoreSessionHandle session, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocol(IChannelSource channelSource, ICoreSessionHandle session, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.Aggregate[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, PipelineDefinition`2 pipeline, AggregateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Aggregate>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.Aggregate[TResult](PipelineDefinition`2 pipeline, AggregateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at RealtorsPropertyResource.Rpr.MongoSearches.Model.QueryPropertiesForKeys[T](PerformanceMonitor performanceMonitor, PropertiesSearchCriteria criteria, RequiredDataResult requiredData)
   at RealtorsPropertyResource.Rpr.MongoSearches.Model.SearchWithMongo(PropertiesSearchCriteria criteria, PerformanceMonitor performanceMonitor)
   at RealtorsPropertyResource.Rpr.MongoSearches.Model.SearchForProperties(PropertiesSearchCriteria criteria, PerformanceMonitor performanceMonitor, Nullable`1 useMongo)
   at RealtorsPropertyResource.Rpr.Websites.Main.AjaxService.ExecuteLoadTestSearch(AppPropertyMode appPropertyMode, SearchType searchType, String query) in C:\BuildAgents\RPR-Website\_work\4\s\Websites\Main\services\AjaxService.Search.cs:line 260
   at SyncInvokeExecuteLoadTestSearch(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

We tested against two Mongo instances, one running on Windows and one running on Linux, and both are hitting this error. The searches that are completing successfully aren't slow, so I'm not confident this is a timeout issue, but perhaps maybe a max connection issue? I'm confused though because I thought the default connection limit for the MongoDB C# driver was 100 connections, and that limit for the MongoDB server itself was much higher than that.

Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this error that only occurs while Mongo is under load?

In case it's relevant, here is how I'm instantiating a singleton MongoClient and IMongoDatabase:

```
public static class MongoContext
    {
        private static bool initialized = false;
        private static string connectionString { get; set; }
        private static IMongoDatabase database;

        public static IMongoDatabase Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("You must initialize the MongoContext first");
                return database;
            }
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                initialized = true;
                connectionString = RprConfigurationManager.GetConnectionString("MongoSearch");
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MongoDB search database: " + connectionString);
                var useSsl = connectionString.IndexOf("ssl=true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;

                var url = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
                var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(url);
                clientSettings.SslSettings = new SslSettings();
                clientSettings.SslSettings.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                clientSettings.UseSsl = useSsl;
                clientSettings.VerifySslCertificate = false;

                var client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
                var lastSegment = connectionString.Split('/').Last();
                var databaseSegments = lastSegment.Split('?');
                var databaseName = databaseSegments.First();
                databaseName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName) ? databaseName : "rpr";
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to database: " + databaseName);
                database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
                SchemaInitializer.RegisterClassMaps();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are some mongod logs, in case it helps:

> IXSCAN { CityPlaceId: 1, ForSaleGroupId: 1, DistressedGroupId: 1,
>   OffMarketGroupId: 1, ForLeaseGroupId: 1, ForSaleDistressedGroupId: 1,
>   OffMarketDistressedGroupId: 1, OrgId: 1, OrgSecurableId: 1,
>   OffMarketDate: 1, IsListingOnly: 1 } keysExamined:397707
>   docsExamined:332738 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:20750
>   nreturned:1 reslen:1454 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 21121 }
>   }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 21121 } }, Collection: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 21121 } } } storage:{ data: { bytesRead:
>   7534883557, timeReadingMicros: 325960940 } } protocol:op_msg 356835ms
>   2019-08-19T19:43:08.856+0000 I NETWORK  [conn285] Error sending
>   response to client: SocketException: An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine.. Ending connection from
>   172.27.129.209:65121 (connection id: 285) 2019-08-19T19:43:08.856+0000 I NETWORK  [conn285] end connection 172.27.129.209:65121 (30
>   connections now open)

Comment: Can we see the full exception and stack trace?

Comment: @PeteGarafano Updated the post with the full stack trace.

Comment: So this is going to be a bit hard to get to the bottom of. If you have any sort of support with MongoDB, I would suggest you start there. It's super hard to solve these things on SO given the back and forth usually required. That being said, this _feels_ like a case of you saturated MongoDB so bad it can no longer accept or maintain connections. I've seen this happen with queries that aren't indexed well. I've done this a few times myself throwing a few thousand insert tasks at the driver. My first suggestion is to check the mongod log for anything interesting. Look for lines ending in "ms"

Comment: @PeteGarafano The search query is intensive, as it leverages the aggregation pipeline to filter down to a set of property listing records (e.g. >$500K in Irvine, CA), ranks the listing records for a given property / sorts by the rank / collapses down to one listing record with the best rank per property (e.g. show the most recent for sale listing record), sorts by something else (e.g. highest number of bedrooms), then grabs a page of results. The indexes are optimized to handle the 1st filter step of the pipeline (as that's all that can use an index), then the rest is handled in memory or disk

Comment: ...so my hope was that Mongo could still handle an intensive query under load and not completely flake out, otherwise this Mongo effort was for not and we should just stick with SQL Server. I've updated the post with an excerpt from the mongod logs where the error occurred.

Comment: Can you post in the MongoDB google groups? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user it is much more suited to the back and forth I think you'll need and either myself or another community member will be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2543?focusedCommentId=2290849&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2290849) is mentioned that can be a problem with the driver, In our case we change the driver version from 2.5 to 2.10 and worked.